# add/subtract not giving accurate values in textbox c#

Tags: c#, textbox, int, subtraction

I am using this code to subtract the discount txtbox value from the orderprice textbox value I have initially 0 in discount textbox and some value in orderprice textbox when I enter in discount textbox it subtracts the value from orderprice but not accurate even if I press backspace button it subtracts value and when I empty the discount textbox it gives error that input string was not in correct format , for example there is 2000 in orderprice and when I enter 200 int discount( first it subtracts 2 from total then 20 and then 200) and in the end  it subtracts and gives 1778 in orderprice textbox and when I backspace it then subtracts 20 more and then 2 more. don't know the solution 
please help Thanks in advance.

```
 private void txt_disc_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {


                try
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_orderprice.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_disc.Text))
                 txt_orderprice.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(txt_orderprice.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(txt_disc.Text)).ToString();
                        txt_orderprice.Update();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Nothing in this question suggests SQL, so I removed the tag.

Comment: The `TextChanged` event will fire on each keystroke. Since you keep subtracting the discount from the most recent, rather than initial, order price the value will keep shrinking.

Comment: what if use another event

Comment: You could use the [`Validating`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and  [`Validated`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validated%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) events, but you still need to address the problem of caching the initial value of order price. A user may enter several values for the discount before finally settling on zero. How do you expect to get back to the original order price?

Comment: Done I have paste the code in keypress (enter) event

Comment: Tip: If you include `@user`, e.g. `@HABO`, in a comment then that user will be notified. More information is [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).

Answer (score 0):

I notice some oddities about the code:
The `if` statement says:
If `txt_orderprice.Text` is NOT null or empty; or
if `txt_disc.Text` IS null or empty.

Check this and correct if you intend them both to have a value.

I suggest you add braces after the `if`. As it stands `txt_orderprice` is always updated, regardless of the `if`.

You could split the two `Convert.ToInt32` calls into separate lines of code and use the debugger to check you are capturing the correct numbers.

Read and use @HABO's comments about the events. The debugger will help you see when the method is called.